# remove all files containing a certain name within a directory

Tags: ansible

I have the following directory and it has the following files:

```
/tmp/test/file1.txt
/tmp/test/file1.txt.backup
/tmp/test/mywords.csv
```

How do I use the `file` module to just remove `file1*` files?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the new fileglob loop, which does this in a single task.

Answer (score 30):

edit: Ansible 2.0 has been released now, so the previous answer should work, and you can also now [loop over fileglobs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4). Note this only works if you are running Ansible locally:

```
- file:
    path: "{{item}}"
    state: absent
  with_fileglob:
    - /tmp/test/file*
```

original answer:

I can't find a way to do this currently without dropping to the shell, however if you can drop to the shell to gather a list of files that match the pattern and save that as a variable, then you can loop over the file module with with_items

Ansible 2.0 will include a "find" module that would get the list for you: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html

Here's a couple of tasks that should do it in ansible 2.0, but I don't have it installed so I haven't tested it and may be accessing the results of the find module incorrectly.

```
- find:
    paths: "/tmp/test"
    patterns: "file*"
  register: result

- file:
    path: "{{item.path}}" #correction code
    state: absent
  with_items: " {{ result.files }}"
```

Comment: Cool.. thanks.  Just need to wait for 2.0 to officially be released and then I'll use it.

Comment: The second solution works, but the first (with fileglobs) is incorrect, because the fileglobs seem to work only on the local filesystem.

See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10115 for more info.

Comment: You are correct Karlos. I've updated my answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the find + file module as shown above, but on ansible < 2.0 I got this error:

```
ERROR: find is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

the following command will do (you may replace the -regex with -name "files1*"):

```
- name: delete files
  shell: 'find /tmp/test/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex "/tmp/test/file1.*" -exec rm -rf {} \;'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not in front of a linux terminal but you can use this if you are trying to ensure you only remove things that are files.  Should work but you might need to tweak it.

```
find . -name files1* -type f -exec basename {} \; | xargs rm
```

Comment: I'm using ansible (IT orchestration tool).  They provide modules to do certain stuff on the remote host.  One of those modules is the file module. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html.  How do you use that module to remove a file.  I would like to use it since it is idempotent rather than a true linux command.  I have a linux command that will already remove it by doing -> rm name*

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: srv-lnx
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - shell: "find /var/tmp/collect -maxdepth 1 -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'"
      register: result

    - debug: var=result

    - fetch: src=/var/tmp/collect/{{ item }} dest=/appl/collect/data flat=yes
      with_items: result.stdout_lines
```