# How to delete *.web files only if they exist

Tags: ansible

I need to create an Ansible playbook to delete the `*.web` files in a specific directory only if the files exists.

OS : cent OS, Redhat 5x, 6x.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
 - stat: path=/opt/app/jboss/configuration/*.web
   register: web
 - shell: rm -rf /opt/app/jboss/configuration/*.web
   when: web.stat.exists
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Why test for existence before deleting?

Comment: Sorry, It was my error. I have multiple requirements like `mv` ,`cp` and `rm` `*.web` only if files exists.  I have validated `mv and cp *web` and it was failed and aborting with no such file or directory...Just noticed `rm` is silently completing without error.

Answer (score 28):

@bruce-p's answer gives a deprecation warning with Ansible 2.0+, but the new with_fileglob gives another option:

```
- file: path={{ item }} state=absent
  with_fileglob: /opt/app/jboss/configuration/*.web
```

(Similar question [remove all files containing a certain name within a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146722/remove-all-files-containing-a-certain-name-within-a-directory) has a similar answer.)

EDIT: As noted below, that won't work; here's an example of "the fancy way":

```
- find:
    paths: /opt/app/jboss/configuration
    patterns: "*.web"
  register: find_results

- file:
    path: "{{ item['path'] }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ find_results['files'] }}"
```

Comment: This will not work since `with_fileglob` only matches files on the system which is running ansible, not the target host.

Comment: Hmm, you're right! @bruce-p's remark "If you really want to get fancy you could use the find module to locate all the files that match your pattern and then invoke the rm command (or better yet use the file module and set state=absent) using a with_items loop to loop over what find returns." is the clean way to do this, I guess -- edited to include an example of that.

Comment: Can you please clarify what module is mentioned here? The file module at the moment does not provide a "with_fileglob" https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html

Comment: It's not part of a particular module, it's just one of the standard lookups: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html

Answer (score 3):

The stat module does not work with wildcards, so the first task will not do what you expect. Most Ansible modules do not support `*`, `?`, etc. wildcards in their parameters unless explicitly documented that they do.  The reason for this is that wildcard expansion is typically handled by your login shell (bash, zsh, etc), so unless the application explicitly supports it then it won't recognize them.

Here's an easy way to verify this:

```
tasks:
  - stat: path=/etc/*.conf
    register: foo

  - debug: var=foo

  - stat: path=/etc/resolv.conf
    register: bar

  - debug: var=bar
```

The output of this is:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "foo": {
            "changed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "path=/etc/*.conf",
                "module_complex_args": {},
                "module_name": "stat"
            },
            "stat": {
                "exists": false
            }
        }
    }
}

TASK: [stat path=/etc/resolv.conf] ********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug var=bar] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "bar": {
            "changed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "path=/etc/resolv.conf",
                "module_complex_args": {},
                "module_name": "stat"
            },
            "stat": {
                "atime": 1446665095.0724516,
                "checksum": "fd75f8cc67e4879fa546cbbd901b211bcb7e1b5e",
                "ctime": 1446840004.4182615,
                "dev": 51713,
                "exists": true,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 146096,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "md5": "a56ca5f7379429d3b358ce922b28039b",
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1446840004.4182615,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/etc/resolv.conf",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 94,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when you specify a single file it returns the results for that file, but when you specify a wildcard it basically returns nothing.

As @udondan implied in his answer, you can just do something like this:

```
- shell: rm -rf /opt/app/jboss/configuration/*.web
```

Since `rm` will silently complete without error if there are 0 matches.

If you really want to get fancy you could use the [find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) module to locate all the files that match your pattern and then invoke the `rm` command (or better yet use the [file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) module and set `state=absent`) using a with_items loop to loop over what `find` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , Just noticed `rm` is silently completing without error... I have the same scenario to `mv or cp *.web` only if files exists. Please let me know the suggestion , I tried `find` but it is throwing no such file or directory error.

Comment: I have tried                                                                                                   `- shell: find /opt/app/jboss/configuration/ -name "*.web" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /backup` and it is working as excepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`rm -rf` does not care if the files exist or not. It will not complain. If the files exist they will be removed. If not, well, then not. But the outcome is the same: same status code, no output. No need to deal with that on Ansible level then.

Comment: Only Ansible will complain: `[WARNING]: Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm`

Comment: @dokaspar Ansible will complain whether or not the file exists and whether or not  you use the `-rf` (or just `-f`, I'm not sure the `-r` is needed here for removing files). You can suppress the warning with `warn: false`.