# Ansible set additionals quotes and break exec

Tags: ansible, yaml

I create playbook (of course, it's only first command, than breaks me exec)

```
---
- hosts:
    test_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: exec bash
      command: "{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - "if [ -f ~/memlog_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt ]; then rm ~/memlog_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt; fi"
```

And have an error:

```
changed: [hdp86] => (item=touch ~/memlog_hdp86.txt)
failed: [hdp86] (item=if [ -f ~/memlog_hdp86.txt ]; then rm ~/memlog_hdp86.txt; fi) => {"changed": false, "cmd": "if '[' -f /home/karmatskiyrg/memlog_hdp86.txt '];' then rm '/home/karmatskiyrg/memlog_hdp86.txt;' fi", "item": "if [ -f ~/memlog_hdp86.txt ]; then rm ~/memlog_hdp86.txt; fi", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

I see: "item" are correct - that's exactly command i need.
But in "cmd" attribute have extra quotes. I think, it breaks me execution of PB.

Why it appead? And how it fix?

Look. There structure of question:
1. I've a command.
2. Exec it by command-module.
3. It breaks with any error.
4. How to fix THIS error.

Comment: So, i try another cmd: "for FILE in /var/log/sa/sa[0-9]*; do sadf -d $FILE -- -r >> ~/memlog_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt; done" And see, it set quotes and give me the same error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete \*.web files only if they exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949595/how-to-delete-web-files-only-if-they-exist)

Comment: no, it doesn't look like... I have specific issue, and i need specific solution for it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got a solution. It doesn't solve the same problem, but it should help to avoid it.

Use bash-script: put it in bash-file, and run it. 
String wrapped by file doesn't break by ansible/command line/bush (i don't know what exactly breaks command).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21601683)

Comment: It does. 
It runs command - that it means it solved a problem. Not solve "how to fix command string", but "how to run bash command with ansible"

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the command module for such a simple task. Ansible has better modules to do that. Command is just a fallback if there is no better module.

Your command should delete the file if it exists, right?

Just use the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/file_module.html#file-module):

```
name: delete file if exists
file:
  path: "~/memlog_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
  state: absent
```

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/file_module.html#file-module

Comment: If i ask how to do it better? I need to resolve current problem, and it's only example. I have another commands i need to exec, and its have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question in a different way then. We don't know what you're looking for if you provide that information in the question.

Comment: How can i "ask question in diff way"? If there's concrete question. U can't understand it in two ways.